# Clean command for cordova/phonegap 3.5

Tags: cordova, cordova-3

I am trying to clean my cordova 3.5 project.
So i try to do as it says at the bottom of this page: http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.5.0/guide_platforms_android_index.md.html#Android%20Platform%20Guide

```
$ /path/to/project/cordova/clean
```

So i navigate to cordova directory in my project

```
:~/Desktop/work/project/platforms/android/cordova$ cd clean
bash: cd: clean: Not a directory

:~/Desktop/work/3.5/10/project/platforms/android/cordova$ clean
No command 'clean' found, did you mean:
 Command 'uclean' from package 'svn-buildpackage' (universe)
 Command 'pclean' from package 'pbuilder-scripts' (universe)
 Command 'clear' from package 'ncurses-bin' (main)
clean: command not found
```

How do i clean the project? In cordova 2.8.1 ant clean worked fine, but in cordova 3.5 ant clean also dosen't work.

cordova build and rest all commands are working fine for me, but how do i clean the project?
All help appreciated!

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Either enter in console:

```
cd <my-project-folder>
./platforms/android/cordova/clean
```

Which is the same as:

```
cordova clean
```

> Cleanup project from build artifacts

Comment: this is fine built it would far more intuitive to do do something like phonegap clean android

Comment: Windows shortcut: `.\platforms\android\cordova\clean`

Answer (score 5):

There's the

```
cordova clean
```

command in the Cordova CLI. It cleans the project.

Comment: I get the following error message: Cordova does not know clean; try `cordova help` for a list of all the available commands.

Comment: @Julisch My current development version of Cordova is 6.1.1 - with that version the cordova clean cmd is available. Test your current Cordova installation with following cmd: cordova --version - it will output your systems current Cordova version. Maybe you need to update to a newer version of Cordova since in old versions the clean cmd is not implemented.