# Build Error -Ionic Cordova fails for android

Tags: android, cordova, ionic3, cordova-plugins

I get following error while running the command "ionic cordova build android --stacktrace" :

```
:generateDebugResources
:mergeDebugResources

:processDebugManifest

:processDebugResources
ERROR: In <declare-styleable> FontFamilyFont, unable to find attribute android:fontVariationSettings
 FAILED
ERROR: In <declare-styleable> FontFamilyFont, unable to find attribute android:ttcIndex

I am using following tools on Window's:
 Editor : VScode

Ionic: C:\Users\xyz>ionic -version
3.19.1
Npm as packagemanager
```

Project Properties:

```
target=android-26
cordova.system.library.1=com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:+
cordova.system.library.2=com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.+
cordova.gradle.include.1=cordova-plugin-appsflyer-sdk/customerapp-cordovaAF.gradle
cordova.gradle.include.2=twitter-connect-plugin/customerapp-twitter.gradle
cordova.system.library.3=com.android.support:support-v4:26.+
cordova.system.library.4=com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+
cordova.system.library.5=com.android.support:support-v4:24.1.1+
cordova.system.library.6=com.android.support:support-v4:+
android.library.reference.1=CordovaLib
```

Answer (score 12):

I had to do the stuff of both the answers above:

In **platforms/android/phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner**:

Search for `compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:+` and replace for `compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:27+'`.

In **platforms/android**:

Search for `cordova.system.library.2=com.android.support:support-v4:+` and replace for `cordova.system.library.2=com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.0`.

Hope it helps.

Comment: This worked for me as well

Answer (score 3):

found this on the ionic forum https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/android-build-broken-after-gradle-dependencies-update-execution-failed-for-task-processdebugresources-com-android-ide-common-process-processexception-failed-to-execute-aapt/109982/134 the suggestion that worked for me was "I got it working, my issue was in the `cordova-plugin-file-opener2`.
 Change `com.android.support:support-v4:+` to `com.android.support:support-v4:23+` in the `plugin.xml` for the `cordova-plugin-file-opener2` in the plugins folder and the node_modules folder. 
Then do the same in the `project.properties` in `platforms/android`.
 My plugin however was the background-geolocation and actually i dont believe i had to make a fix in the `project.properties` for mine.

Comment: I may sound naive as I am .So you need to look for them after adding the platform (android) to the ionic project or prior to that?

Comment: I may sound naive as I am .So you need to look for them after adding the platform (android) to the ionic project or prior to that?  Before adding platform(android) I do not see any plugin with 'com.android.support:support-v4:+' .After adding platform(android) I see following plugins has them:cordova-plugin-camera,cordova.plugins.diagnostic,de.appplant.cordova.plugin.local-notification . I made the changes as suggested by you but it still does not build. Any suggestion?Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

Mine required a similar fix as above only it was in the de.appplant.cordova.plugin.local-notification plugin. I changed ‘com.android.support:support-v4:+’ to ‘com.android.support:support-v4:23+’ and then removed and added the android platform and it built. However, I had an extra brace '}' in my build-extras.gradle that had to be removed also.

Comment: If I remove and add android, androidmenifest file is not added again,hence leading to build failure.Any more suggestion?

Comment: Thanks! This worked for me on an Ionic app (as stated in his answer, the key for me was removing and adding back the android platform)

Answer (score 2):

In my case, problem was in barcode scanner plug in. Removing and adding this plug in did not work, after all get it worked by changing **'com.android.support:support-v4:+'** to **'com.android.support:support-v4:27+'** in file **'platform/android/phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner/{projectName}-barcodescanner'**. What I did not understand is project was working yesterday perfectly, what happened in 24 hours and this problem occured...

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue, what I did was following:

1. Clear the build directory

   - cordova clean
2. Add multiDexEnabled under android -> defaultConfig to the build.gradle file

   - "your project\platforms\android\app\build.gradle"
   - multiDexEnabled true
3. Change dependencies for "com.android.support" within the build.gradle file

   - com.android.support:support-v4:+ => com.android.support:support-v4:23+
4. Go through the plugins folder and look in all "plugins.xml" and replace:

   - com.android.support:support-v4:+ => com.android.support:support-v4:23+
5. Change project.properties under "platforms\android\project.properties"

   - cordova.system.library.4=com.android.support:support-v4:23+
6. Run "ionic cordova run build"

Unable to merge dex

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/46591042
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/47746531

Clean install

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/24684622

Wrong Namespace / Version

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/49164846

.

```
android {

    defaultConfig {
        multiDexEnabled true
        versionCode cdvVersionCode ?: new BigInteger("" + privateHelpers.extractIntFromManifest("versionCode"))
        applicationId privateHelpers.extractStringFromManifest("package")

        if (cdvMinSdkVersion != null) {
            minSdkVersion cdvMinSdkVersion
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did not find "com.android.support:support-v4:+" in the indicated paths of the topics I searched for, as I tried lastly in all folders and found in

> platforms/android/phonegap-plugin-**barcodescanner**.gradle

in my case the plugin was the **barcodescanner**, in yours may be another.
 then I followed the information and replaced with "'com.android.support:support-v4:27+" and it worked.

I was wondering if it was working perfectly yesterday, today I changed only one text and gave this error ... during the build I realized that some downloads occurred I believe that an update happened that caused this.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem out of the blue yesterday. It started randomly but from reading around, it looks like it is to do with an update as mentioned above by @cpro90. However, I tried and could not find where to make the necessary manual change.

Eventually I identified that the problem was being caused by my cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview plugin. On Github, I found the issue on the plugin repro this morning and it had over 520 views by lunch.

@UNUMObile suggested the following in the build.gradle file to force an earlier version globally:

```
    configurations.all {
       resolutionStrategy.force 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.0.0'
    }
```

This worked immediately for me and may help others with other plugins that also have had their dependancy on 'com.android.support:support-4:<28. The new version 28 seems to be the issue.

Hope this helps someone move forward.

Comment: Sorry to bug you, but *where* would you put this?

more specifically, I'm trying to build in ionic's pro cloud-based builder.  It seems making any change to any dependency's gradle files won't work, because the unmodified versions would be pulled down by the remote build system.  

Any one else face this issue?

Comment: Add straight after buildscript section closing curly brace at the top of the file.

Answer (score 0):

Replacing **'com.android.support:support-v4:+'** and **'com.android.support:support-v4:27+'** with fixed versions in the plugin.xml didn't work for us - cordova crosswalk updated at least one support library to version **28.0.0-alpha1** though.

Forcing a fixed version of the support library for each dependency could solve the problem in the end.

```
configurations.all {
resolutionStrategy {
    eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
        if (details.requested.group == 'com.android.support') {
            details.useVersion "27.1.0"
        }
    }
}
```